# how to replace parenthesis "( )" with space if before and after characters are not space, else remove parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

i want my text to convert into *args deep deep peed*

```
    import re
    originalFile = "args(deep) ( deep ) peed)"
    print(originalFile)
    originalFile = re.sub(r'((\s+)[\( \)])',r'', re.sub(r'([A-Za-z0-                9][\( \)])',r' ', originalFile))
    print(originalFile)
```

but on running the code i get the output

```
    args(deeo) ( deep ) peed)
    arg dee dee pee
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regex like the following one (with a space as replacement) with a subsequent call to `strip()` right after:

```
\s*[()][\s()]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZUYu6D/1/).

**Regex details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[()]` - a `)` or `(`
- `[\s()]*` - 0+ whitespaces, `(` or `)` chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/GWQeEe):

```
import re
originalFile = "args(deep) ( deep ) peed)"
print(re.sub(r"\s*[()][\s()]*", " ", originalFile).strip())
# => args deep deep peed
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

You can replace each parenthesis with a space and then filter multiple spaces:

```py
import re
t = t.replace("(", " ")
t = t.replace(")", " ")
re.sub(' +', ' ', t)
```

#### Method 2

Use the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/8mv6EH/1):

```py
re.sub("(\s*[()]\s*)+", " ", t)
```

Comment: Please refrain from repeating infinite number of times groups where the first and last patterns are `*` quantified and can match the same type of chars (here, `\s*`), this might lead to problems with  performance in most scenarios. In my pattern, `\s*[()][\s()]*`, you may see that I match whitespaces first, then parentheses as an obligatory char, and then any number of whitespace or parentheses, and thus there is no way to match the same char type with each subsequent pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew noted!